# jest snapshot testing: how to ignore part of the snapshot file in jest test results

Tags: react-native, jestjs, snapshot

Problem: ignore some part of the .snap file test results

the question here: there are some components in my test that have a random values and i don't really care about testing them. is there any way to ignore part of my X.snap file? so when i run tests in the future it won't give me test fail results.

Answer (score 44):

Now you can also use [property matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#property-matchers) for these cases.

By example to be able to use snapshot with these object :

```
const obj = {
  id: dynamic(),
  foo: 'bar',
  other: 'value',
  val: 1,
};
```

You can use :

```
expect(obj).toMatchSnapshot({
  id: expect.any(String),
});
```

Jest will just check that id is a String and will process the other fields in the snapshot as usual.

Comment: @MichaelBrawn yes, with this syntax : `toMatchSnapshot({id: expect.any(String)}, "snapshot name")`

Answer (score 35):

Actually, you need to mock the moving parts.

As stated in [jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/snapshot-testing.html#tests-should-be-deterministic):

> Your tests should be deterministic. That is, running the same tests multiple times on a component that has not changed should produce the same results every time. You're responsible for making sure your generated snapshots do not include platform specific or other non-deterministic data.

If it's something related to time, you could use

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => 1482363367071);
```

Comment: At first, this sounded weird, but then I realized, this should actually work for `Math.random`, so my use-case should be covered.

Comment: What if for example your id is the hash of a commit that does changes (i.e; head ref) ?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's quite old question but I know one more solution. You can modify property you want to ignore, so it will be always constant instead of random / dynamic. This is best for cases when you are using third party code and thus may not be able to control the non deterministic property generation
Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Card from './Card';
import toJSON from 'enzyme-to-json';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<Card />', () => {
    it('renders <Card /> component', () => {
        const card = shallow(
            <Card
                baseChance={1}
                name={`test name`}
                description={`long description`}
                imageURL={'https://d2ph5fj80uercy.cloudfront.net/03/cat1425.jpg'}
                id={0}
                canBeIgnored={false}
                isPassive={false}
            />
        );
        const snapshot = toJSON(card);

        // for some reason snapshot.node.props.style.backgroundColor = "#cfc5f6" 
        // does not work, seems the prop is being set later
        Object.defineProperty(snapshot.node.props.style, 'backgroundColor', { value: "#cfc5f6", writable: false });

        // second expect statement is enaugh but this is the prop we care about:
        expect(snapshot.node.props.style.backgroundColor).toBe("#cfc5f6");
        expect(snapshot).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. Based on your approach I made a simple function that is called on snapshot and snapshot.children recursively and will that function will replace any non deterministic properties.
Also you can edit your answer to mention that this approach is best for cases when you are using third party code and thus may not be able to control the non deterministic property generation

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore some parts in the snapshot tests replacing the properties in the HTML. Using jest with testing-library, it would look something like this:

```
it('should match snapshot', async () => {
  expect(removeUnstableHtmlProperties(await screen.findByTestId('main-container'))).toMatchSnapshot();
});

function removeUnstableHtmlProperties(htmlElement: HTMLElement) {
  const domHTML = prettyDOM(htmlElement, Infinity);
  if (!domHTML) return undefined;
  return domHTML.replace(/id(.*)"(.*)"/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to override moment's `fromNow` to make my snapshots deterministic:

```
import moment, {Moment} from "moment";

moment.fn.fromNow = jest.fn(function (this: Moment) {
  const withoutSuffix = false;
  return this.from(moment("2023-01-12T20:14:00"), withoutSuffix);
});
```