# How to ignore a particular HTML element in a Jest snapshot?

Tags: html, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, snapshot

I'm modifying a Jest test which looks like this:

```
it("footer exists as expected", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Footer />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

The snapshot looks like this:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing

exports[`test header consistency  footer exists as expected 1`] = `
<footer
  className="makeStyles-footer-1"
  id="footer"
  role="contentinfo"
>
  <div
    className="makeStyles-content-2"
  >
    <div>
      ... (version number within a nested HTML element)
</footer>
`;
```

Nested within the HTML is a version number that I'd like to exclude from the snapshot comparison. How could this be done? (Am looking for the simplest way.)

*Note: Did come across a small bit of Jest documentation which looked promising but only excluded an example for a simple JSON object: https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing#property-matchers - and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935903#answer-51218533) does similar. Could this be adapted for a nested HTML structure?*

Comment: toJSON returns an object and you can modify it the way you need to process a snapshot. I'm not sure if there are tools that do this for you.

Comment: Where does that version number _come from_?

Comment: So looking at the JSON (thanks @EstusFlask), the version number would be in the following place: `tree.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[1]`. So I tried `expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot({      children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[1]: expect.any(String)})` but square brackets aren't allowed...

Comment: @jonrsharpe See above - the version number is the text in a nested HTML element (with the following xpath if it helps: `//*[@id="footer"]/div/div/p[1]/a/text()[2]`)

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's _shown_ in the footer, I'm asking: where does the component get it from to show it? Is it hard-coded in the component (and if so how and when does it get updated)? If it is (or can be) externalised to a prop or context then it becomes trivial to control it in the test.

Comment: Oh I see. It comes from the package.json file and gets updated every time we do a release. What I'm trying to fix is the test failing due to an upgrade - it should just ignore the version number but check everything else. Would ideally still want to carry on with snapshots in the same way as before (e.g. generating them with `jest -u`) - just ignore this very specific thing in the snapshot.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks @jonrsharpe I now understand where you were coming from. Added the following *before* the expect call and the test is now working: `tree.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[1] = \`{version}\``. (If you'd like to formulate this as an answer I'll gladly accept...)

Comment: The direction I was coming from was more that if you have e.g. `import { version } from "path/to/package.json"` then you can `jest.mock("path/to/package.json")` and provide a fixed value for the tests rather than relying on it being stable elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you can replace it with a placeholder. I don't think it's necessary to put the exact value there, at least if you have more specific test to assert that.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Mocking does seem the best way to go, any further advice on how to do this? Tried this but it doesn't work: `jest.mock("../../../../package.json", () => { version: "dummyVersion" })`

Comment: That's feasibly just a syntax mistake; an arrow function returning an object looks like `() => ({ this })`, otherwise the braces indicate the function body. Aside from that I'd need to see a [mre].

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly the issue - thanks so much for your help with this @jonrsharpe.